# Apply gradient to line vue chart.js

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, gradient, background-color, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to apply a gradient to the background color, but I'm not applying it. I did as I saw in several tutorials and even so it doesn't apply the gradient.

First I created a computed to change the gradient as needed.
Access this computed through the 'data' which returns the gradient value to be used for a variable.

And finally I created 3 methods 'changeDados' which is to click on a button to change the values ​​of the graph, 'changeTema' which is to switch between the dark and light theme, and 'fillData' which is the original function of the vuechart to apply the values ​​on the graph.

the code

```
  computed: {
    colorGradient() {
      var gradientFill = this.$refs.canvas
        .getContext("2d")
        .createLinearGradient(0, 500, 0, 100);
      gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(63, 255, 243, 0.4)");
      gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(89, 198, 184, 0)");
      return gradientFill;
    }
  },
```

```
  data() {
    return {
      gradient: this.colorGradient
    };
  }
```

```
methods: {
    changeDados() {
      var change = new Array();
      change = [
        3000,
        8000,
        1000,
        6000,
        1000,
        6000,
        5000,
        9000,
        1000,
        1000,
        2000,
        3000,
        4000,
        3000,
        6000,
        7000,
        2000,
        4000,
        1000,
        2000,
        3000,
        4000,
        3000,
        6000,
        7000,
        2000,
        4000
      ];
      this.dadosGraph = change;

      this.datacollection = {
        labels: this.datasGraph,
        datasets: [
          {
            borderColor: "#3CFFD0",
            borderWidth: 2,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
            pointBorderColor: "#3CFFD0",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#3CFFD0",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#3CFFD0",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "#3CFFD0",
            backgroundColor: this.gradient,
            data: this.testeDados
          }
        ]
      };
    },
    mudarTema() {
      if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "dark") {
        this.datacollection = {
          labels: this.datasGraph,
          datasets: [
            {
              borderColor: "#3CFFD0",
              borderWidth: 2,
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
              pointBorderColor: "#3CFFD0",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#3CFFD0",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#3CFFD0",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "#3CFFD0",
              backgroundColor: this.gradient,
              data: this.testeDados
            }
          ]
        };
      }
      if (this.themeValue == "light") {
        this.datacollection = {
          labels: this.datasGraph,
          datasets: [
            {
              borderColor: "#3CFFD0",
              borderWidth: 2,
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
              pointBorderColor: "#3CFFD0",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#3CFFD0",
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#3CFFD0",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "#3CFFD0",
              backgroundColor: this.gradient,
              data: this.testeDados
            }
          ]
        };
      }
    },

    fillData() {
      this.mudarTema();
    }
  }
```

template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="view" :class="[{ collapsed: collapsed }]">
      <router-view />
    </div>
    <sidebar-menu
      class="sidebar"
      :menu="menu"
      :collapsed="collapsed"
      @item-click="onItemClick"
      @collapse="onCollapse"
      style="z-index: 1; "
    />
    <div class="bodyDiv">
    <nav id="navigator" class="navbar" :class="{navbaropen: opened}">
      <span class="open-slide">
        <a href="#" @click="opened = !opened">
          <div>
            <div class="bar" :class="{topopen: opened}"></div>
            <div class="bar" :class="{midopen: opened}"></div>
            <div class="bar" :class="{botopen: opened}"></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </span>
    </nav>
  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav" :class="{sidenavopen: opened}">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
      <div id="main" :class="{mainopen: opened}">-->

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="container">
        <DataRangePicker
          style="margin:50px;background-color:#273D3D;box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #041B16; border-radius: 5px; padding:10px;"
          v-on:submit="updateRanges"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="row" style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 60px; z-index: 2; ">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <h2
            align="left"
            style="font-family:Poppins; font-style: normal;padding:15px;"
          >Análise de Consumo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
          <br />
          <h6 style="display:inline; padding-right:10px; padding-top:30px">Bem-vindo, Ivan</h6>
          <input type="checkbox" id="theme-switch" class="theme-switch" v-model="darkMode" />
          <label for="theme-switch">
            <span v-if="darkMode === true">
              <img alt="logo" src="./assets/images/moonNew.svg" width="20" />
            </span>
            <span v-else>
              <img alt="logo" src="./assets/images/sunNew.svg" width="30" />
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <b-row style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;">
        <b-col cols="10"></b-col>
        <b-col align="right"></b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 30px;">
        <b-col cols="12" style="padding: 0px">
          <div
            style="background-color:#273D3D; margin: 20px 100px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #041B16; border-radius: 5px;"
          >
            <div align="right" style="padding:17px 60px;">
              <button-group
                style="box-shadow: -2px -2px 6px #2F4949, 2px 2px 6px #1F3131; border: 0px;border-radius: 5px;"
              />
            </div>
            <div align="center">
              <chart-teste :jsonT="pref" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you paste the template as well, it will be helpful to answer your issue with it.

Comment: I will insert the template